# Переключение пользователя БД

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

У меня возникла необходимость ограничивать доступ к данным не только на уровне приложения но и на уровне БД.
Я сделал все следующим образом в **application_controller.rb**:

```
before_filter :set_db_connection

def set_db_connection
    unless current_user.nil?
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => "oracle_enhanced",
        :database     => "host/XE",
        :username => current_user.db_login,
        :password => current_user.db_password

      )
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('alter session set current_schema = db_schema')
    end
  end
```

Правильно ли я решил данную задачу, и не может ли возникнуть проблем с таким решением?

Comment: Вы проверили, это вообще работает?

Comment: конечно проверил)

Comment: Тогда у меня только сомнения по поводу thread safety этого кода. Но если вы гоняете систему на однопоточных воркерах вроде тех, что у Unicorn, проблем быть не должно. В теории.

Comment: честно говоря я пользуюсь Phusion passenger, и когда тестировал на нем, был такой баг, что если авторизоваться и не производить не каких действий примерно минут 10-15 на странице, а потом сделать get запрос на сервер, то вываливалась ошибка, проходила она только после нажатия F5 в браузере.

Comment: У вас одни креды базы на какие примерно количества конечных пользователей рассчитаны?

Comment: пока это не однозначный вопрос, но думаю на 100-200 максимум внутри локальной сети

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так

```
def set_db_connection
  if current_user.present?
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_cache!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "oracle_enhanced",
      :database     => "host/XE",
      :username => current_user.db_login,
      :password => current_user.db_password
      )
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('alter session set current_schema = db_schema')
  end
end
```

и поглядел посмотрел нет ли того что мне нужно в геме [db-charmer](https://github.com/kovyrin/db-charmer)

Comment: ага, я понял, вы немного поменяли проверку, и добавили очистку кеша, где то я читал что ее желательно делать перед переподключением, но упустил это, спасибо за совет! Гем надо будет поглядеть, я его уже встречал, но детально не разбирал его принцип работы.

Comment: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced поглядите ещё

Comment: oracle-enhanced тут точно не помощник. И про db-charmer из их документации:
Warning: All the connection switching calls would switch connection only for those classes the method called on. You can’t call the switch_connection_to method and switch connection for a base class in some hierarchy (for example, you can’t switch ActiveRecord::Base connection and see all your models switched to the new connection, use the classic establish_connection instead).
Т.е. если производить переключение то для каждой модели отдельно, что не совсем мне подходит.

Comment: и у меня к вам дополнительный вопрос созрел, вы другом посте вы сказали что для данной задачи больше подходит пассенджер, и что вы такое уже делали в продакшене, для пассенджера или nginx не нужны какие либо дополнительные настройки?

Comment: Да, там как то очень хитро настраивали пятого пессенджера. Отпишусь как узнаю

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не уверен в том, что это будет корректно работать в продакшене.

Например unicorn создаёт сразу несколько воркеров, которые сразу подключаются к базе. Как минимум, такой подход приведёт к тому, что будут тратиться дополнительные ресурсы на создаение нового подключения буквально при каждом обновлении страницы. Не говоря уж про дополнительные административные расходы на поддержание в актуальном состоянии логина и пароля от базы в таблице пользователей.

Вообще задача сама по себе неправильная. Согласно концепции Rails база данных - "тупое" хранилище. Добавлять ограничение (как и любую другую логику) в базу данных - оверхед. Плюс стоит учитывать, что если приложение попытается сделать что-то, что запрещено на уровне бд - пользователь получит 500.

Если возникает подобная задача, я бы начал с того, что:

1. Посмотрел имеющиееся гемы для авторизации пользователей. Например [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) или [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). Они достаточно мощные и помогают достаточно гибко решить многие задачи авторизации.
2. Пересмотрел структуру проекта.
3. Если не помогло 1 и 2 и всё равно очень надо настраивать права на уровне СУБД - поднял бы несколько копий приложения и разнёс их по поддоменам. А с основого домена редиректил бы на поддомен, в зависимости от текущего пользователя. Например:

   - `clients.my-site.ru` - поддомен для клиентов, где в конфиге БД задан пользователь с ролью "клиент".
   - `admins.my-site.ru` - поддомен для админстраторов, где в конфиге БД задан пользователь с ролью "admin".
   - т.д.

Но это очень сложный и скользкий путь. Следует как следует подумать прежде чем идти по нему.

**UPD**
Согласно [статье](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fernandez-rails-connections-101759.html) на офф. сайте оракла, нет стандартного способа сделать Pass-Through. Попытки (в том числе и предложеная автором вопроса) приведут к потерям производительности.

Comment: Я с вами в корне не согласен про "тупое" хранилище и "концепцию рельс". Вероятно вы имели в виду уровень абстракции? Так никто же не мешает спустится по абстракциям на уровень ниже и сделать так как требует задача (а задача требует разделение прав на уровне базы, это же оракл)

Если мы имели в виду, модель == таблица, тогда да.

Но база может быть как угодно спроектирована, хоть по базе на модель (-:

Comment: Ну то есть "тупость" базы от изменений establish_connection не пострадает. Я делал такое в продакшене.
Нужно использовать пассенгер, не юникорн (для данной задачи).

Comment: собственно говоря я и так использую cancancan, с правами в приложении у меня все как нельзя лучше, каждую мелочь можно настроить и т.д. Дело в том что как говорят ораклисты это дополнительная защита, убедить их в том что это особо не чего не даст для веб приложения, мне не удалось.

Comment: @Vetal4eg, я имел ввиду что с точки зрения рельс (кстати, не только их) вся логика приложения должна быть реализована в приложении. А вот такая авторизация, равно как и, например, хранимые процедуры делают её неочевидной.
Пассажир не даст желаемого результата. Как и в случае юникорна, приложение инициализируется (вместе с соединением к бд) при старте демона. По большому счёту, разница в том как они управляют воркерами.

Comment: @Alexander, вот это я и имел ввиду когда говорил про оверхед. Можно до бесконечности перестраховываться, но это уже переходит в паранойю. Добавил в ответ ссылку на статью. Возможно оркалистам стоит её показать.

Comment: @Alexander, и ещё про оверхед. Допустим понадобится изменить права. Получатся дополнительные затраты на синхронизацию канкана и оракла. К тому же, я не уверен что хранить в базе пароль от базы - хорошая идея.

Comment: @anoam безусловно я с вами согласен в том что веб приложения так не делаются, бизнес логина и разграничение прав должно лежать полностью на веб-приложении, а если нужно написать еще desktop app то использовать REST API к тому же веб приложению. Но пока я не доказал что это паранойя, я ищу решение.